# Spring 3.2 Date time format

Tags: spring

I am using standalone Spring framework and I want to implement Spring 3.2 @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/mm/yyyy"), but not getting the expected output.

My code snippet is:

```
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/mm/yyyy")
      private Date dob;


    public void  amehotd(){

    Calendar cal;
      cal = Calendar.getInstance ();
          cal.set (1999, Calendar.AUGUST, 30);
          this.dob = cal.getTime();
          System.out.println(dob)    
    }
```

Gives following result:

```
Mon Aug 30 15:08:14 CDT 1999
```

but I was expecting output like: 30/08/1999

I want to implement without joda time library

Comment: How do you "print" that output? I ask because it looks like the annotation is not taken in account at all.

Comment: I would use the [Joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) API (as it is always my preference) and certainly not the Java SE default date time APIs. If you're using Spring 3.2, then you can register a custom property editor directly with [`@ControllerAdvice`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html)  to meet whatever you need.

Answer (score 22):

Try changing the format to :

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
```

`MM` is for months , `mm` for minutes .

Just look at this [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.ISO.html):

> The most common ISO DateTime Format **yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSZ** e.g.

Comment: @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
   private Date dob;              but still getting: Mon Aug 30 15:28:22 CDT 1999

Answer (score 14):

I know it's an old question but I answer because I had the same problem today and I lost 4 hours of work to find the solution. The problem here is spring uses Jackson to serialize and deserialize JSON. `@DateTimeFormat` annotation will not do the job, you have to tell Jackson how to serialize the date. You have two solutions: the first one is the simplier and is to use `@JsonFormat` annotation in the getter method:

```
@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")
public Date getDob(){
    return dob;
}
```

The second solution is to create a custom serializer for date fields like this:

```
public class JsonDateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date>{

    private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    @Override
    public void serialize(Date date, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

        gen.writeString(formattedDate);
    }
}
```

and then use the annotation in the get method:

```
@JsonSerialize(using=JsonDateSerializer.class)
public Date getDob(){
   return dob; 
}
```

this link explains how to do the serializer

https://dzone.com/articles/how-serialize-javautildate

I faced another problem, I was importing in my JsonDateSerializer class the classes from `org.codehaus.jackson` package, but Spring gived me this error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/codehaus/jackson/map/JsonSerializer.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

So I changed all the imports to the package

```
com.fasterxml.jackson
```

and it all works fine.
I hope it can help someone.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `System.out.println` directly in a method of your class. This can't work that way.

You have to call the `dob` field from outside of your class, for instance from a JSP page. And this way, the field will be automatically formatted to the given pattern.

Answer (score 1):

@NumberFormat and @DateTimeFormat annotations work only in Spring MVC environment. You have to use `<mvc:annotation-driven/>`
in your xml mvc configration file.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your imports in your class.  Your date type should be java.util.Date.  It might be inheriting from a different class, such as, java.sql.Date.