# Date in jsp is not same as nls_date_format spfile value

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, oracle11gr2

The database is Oracle 11g2 Express.

I changed the nls_date_format to `DD/MM/RRRR` :

```
alter system set nls_date_format = "DD/MM/RRRR" scope = spfile;
```

Then I restarted the database.

Now in my spring-mvc project I created a Bean :

```
@Entity

@Table(name = "HR.EMPLOYEES")

public class User {


    @Id

    @SequenceGenerator(name="EMPLOYEES_SEQ", sequenceName="EMPLOYEES_SEQ", allocationSize=1)

    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="EMPLOYEES_SEQ")

    @Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_ID")

    private int id;



    @Formula(value="FIRST_NAME || ' ' || LAST_NAME")

    private String username;



    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")

    private String firstname;



    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")

    private String lastname;



    private String email;



    @Column(name="HIRE_DATE")

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)

    private Date hireDate; // java.util.Date



    private String job_id;



    @Column(name = "SALARY")

    private double salary;



    public int getId() {

        return id;

    }

    public void setId(int id) {

        this.id = id;

    }

    public String getUsername() {

        return username;

    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {

        this.username = username;

    }

    public String getFirstname() {

        return firstname;

    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {

        this.firstname = firstname;

    }

    public String getLastname() {

        return lastname;

    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {

        this.lastname = lastname;

    }

    public String getEmail() {

        return email;

    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {

        this.email = email;

    }

    public Date getHireDate() {

        return hireDate;

    }

    public void setHireDate(Date hireDate) {

        this.hireDate = hireDate;

    }

    public String getJob_id() {

        return job_id;

    }

    public void setJob_id(String job_id) {

        this.job_id = job_id;

    }

    public double getSalary() {

        return salary;

    }

    public void setSalary(double salary) {

        this.salary = salary;

    }



}
```

Here is DAO Implementation :

```
public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {



    @Autowired

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;



    public UserDAOImpl() {



    }



    public UserDAOImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {

        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;

    }


    @Override

    @Transactional

    public List<User> list() {        

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

        List<User> listUser = (List<User>) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()

        .createCriteria(User.class)

        .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY).list();

        return listUser;

    }


    @Override

    @Transactional

    public User get(int id) {



        String hql = "from User where id=" + id;

        Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);



        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

        List<User> listUser = (List<User>) query.list();



        if (listUser != null && !listUser.isEmpty()) {

            return listUser.get(0);

        }



        return null;



    }


    @Override

    @Transactional

    public void saveOrUpdate(User user) {

        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(user);

    }


    @Override

    @Transactional

    public void delete(int id) {

        User userToDelete = new User();

        userToDelete.setId(id);

        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(userToDelete);

    }


}
```

Here is the controller :

```
@Controller

public class HomeController {



    @Autowired

    private UserDAO userDao;


    @RequestMapping("/")

    public ModelAndView handleRequest() throws Exception { // to list employees

        List<User> listUsers = userDao.list();

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("UserList");

        model.addObject("userList", listUsers);

        return model;

    }



    @RequestMapping(value = "/new", method = RequestMethod.GET)

    public ModelAndView newUser() { // to add a new employee

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("UserForm");

        model.addObject("user_details", new User());

        model.addObject("titre", "Ajout");

        return model;      

    }



    @RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)

    public ModelAndView editUser(HttpServletRequest request) { // to edit an existing employee

        int userId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));

        User user = userDao.get(userId);

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("UserForm");

        model.addObject("user_details", user);

        model.addObject("titre", "Modif");

        return model;      

    }



    @RequestMapping(value = "/delete", method = RequestMethod.GET)

    public ModelAndView deleteUser(HttpServletRequest request) { // to delete an existing employee

        int userId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));

        userDao.delete(userId);

        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/");     

    }



    @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)

    public ModelAndView saveUser(@ModelAttribute User user) { // to execute the dml of insert of update about an employee's data

        userDao.saveOrUpdate(user);

        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/");

    }



}
```

Here is the JSP for editing an employee :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>

<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<html>

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<title>${titre}</title>

<style type="text/css">

    a {

        text-decoration: none;

    }

</style>

</head>

<body>

    <div align="center">

        <h1>${titre}</h1>

        <table>

            <form:form action="save" method="post" modelAttribute="user_details">



                <form:hidden path="id"/>



                <tr>

                    <td>Firstname:</td>

                    <td><form:input path="firstname"/></td>

                </tr>

                <tr>

                    <td>Lastname:</td>

                    <td><form:input path="lastname"/></td>

                </tr>

                <tr>

                    <td>Email:</td>

                    <td><form:input path="email"/></td>

                </tr>

                <tr>

                    <td>Hiredate:</td>

                    <td><form:input path="hireDate"/></td> <%-- this is the date field --%>

                </tr>

                <tr>

                    <td>Job_id:</td>

                    <td><form:input path="job_id"/></td>

                </tr>

                <tr>

                    <td>Salary:</td>

                    <td><form:input path="salary"/></td>

                </tr>

                <tr>

                    <td>

                        <input type="submit" value="Save">

                    </td>

                    <td><a href="<c:url value='/' />"><input type="button" value="Annuler" /></a></td>

                </tr>

            </form:form>

        </table>

    </div>



</body>

</html>
```

At runtime the value displayed in the text field for hire_date has a format `RRRR-MM-DD` , and the only accepted format to be able to be inserted/updated into the database is `MM/DD/RRRR` ! Although spfile `nls_date_format` is already set to `DD/MM/RRRR` and database is already restarted ! So why is the spfile parameter not effect !

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not a database configuration problem but is a Spring problem. Spring uses Jackson to serialize JSON and Jackson handles serialization and deserialization of dates by default to use GMT timestamp format, unless otherwise configured.

If you annotate the date field with `@Temporal`, Spring will show the date in this format: *YYYY-MM-DD*.
 You need to create a custom serializer for date fields to solve the problem and annotate the get method of your date fields with the `@JsonSerialize(using=JsonDateSerializer.class)` annotation.

*JsonDateSerializer* would be your custom serializer class.

See my answer at this question for all the procedure:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38186623/6503002

Answer (score 0):

I found a simpler solution [here](https://gerrydevstory.com/2013/05/21/binding-date-form-input-on-spring-mvc/)

Comment: in your case it works using @DateTimeFormat? in my case didn't.